# Time series Data Analysis and Forecasting by country and time factor

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

cty year qtr tl

Argentina 2009 Q4 3

Argentina 2010 Q1 2

Argentina 2010 Q2 7

Argentina 2010 Q3 7

Argentina 2010 Q4 10

Argentina 2011 Q1 7

Argentina 2011 Q2 7

Argentina 2011 Q3 1

Argentina 2011 Q4 7

Argentina 2012 Q1 5

The data set has around 40 countries with each country having data for 5 years and four quarters. cty=country, year=Year, qtr Quarter, var=count of people. As I am new to R, can someone assist me with how to prepare the dataset for time series and fit a ARIMA/ARMA models etc. followed by the forecast in R? Some basic codes to prepare the data, to perform analysis and forecast for this series as an example would be helpful.